# How can I get the display name of an object in AzureAD using REST API if I have object ID?

Tags: c#, azure, rest, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

After getting `Keyvaults` from Azure REST API, in the access policies there is an `object ID` which I guess is unique. 
Can I use that `object ID` to get the display name from another REST API?

I found similar `powershell` command at [powerShell-Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadobjectbyobjectid?view=azureadps-2.0) but I need it to be done with a REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could request this API:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/getByIds
Content-type: application/json

{
    "ids":["object-id1","object-id2"],
    "types":["user"]
}
```

Response:

[image]

For more details, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-getbyids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what i was looking for!
:D